# Crystal Reports with SQL CE

Tags: crystal-reports, .net-3.5

I've been pulling my hair out trying to get some data to come across to my report. I first used the Microsoft Report viewer, but after trying Crystal Reports - I like the way Crystal Reporting is set up.

The only problem is I can't get a single peice of data to come across from my sql ce DB. I've got a dataset I used as the datasource, thats linked to the proper db - yet nothing comes across.

I even used the report wizard to start off with, specifying the dataset, and report options - called the form - and nothing - only static report headers. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you haven't solved this yourself in the 2 days since you first posted:

1. Do you get the same problem when you connect to another datasource?  What if you make a little dummy table in an MS Access db and connect to it?
2. Data won't display in Crystal until you have at least 1 db field in the Details section. Try adding 1 manually and then go to Preview.
3. In your Field Explorer, go to your Database Fields, right click on a field and Browse. Does any data show up or is the little popup window blank?

Comment: 1. If I connect to a test Access DB - I get data in the Browse Data field context menu
2. I did that with the access DB and it works fine
3. Not with MY sql ce database, but it does with the Access DB
I think the problem is I'm not passing any data. I've read up some on datasets and tableadapters (its been awhile). But all examples show how to pass 1 table of data in. I need to pass 4 tables of data in.

Comment: I see a potential solution here. How about using Access as a middleman? i.e. Crystal connects to Access queries which connect to your real DB. The Access queries can be really simple ("Select * from whatever"). It feels unnecessarily complex, but if it works, it works.

Comment: Right, honestly my db isnt keeping historical data - Im just having to use the DB for crystal reports to work "nicely". I can probably just re-code my data access to work with an Access DB instead of SQL CE db.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Part of the problem was that it was copying the db to the bin/debug directory - and crystal reports was setup to read the main directory. I've actually switched to an Access DB and got everything working just fine.

Comment: Well, I still can't explain what the original problem was, but I'm glad you found a way around it.

Comment: I wasn't getting any data in my Crystal Report